# What is the maximum range of Torbjorn's turret, if any?

Tags: overwatch

I have seen conflicting sources on this - some claiming the turret range is infinite, or at least functionally so, while others have held that the range was 25 or 40 metres.  Does anyone have verified post launch data on this, or maybe a video of a character being at a safe distance from the turret?

Specifically, I'm looking for post launch information; the pre launch question I've seen on here is one of the conflicting sources I mentioned.